# Replacing a specific cell value of dataframe based on other column

Tags: pandas, dataframe, google-translate

In my dataframe of google translator their is column as language which contains nan value, now I want to replace the value of nan with the detected language of other column which contains comments in multiple languages. For example 1.  If Comment is in **en** so Language column should get updated with English. 2. Comment is in **th** so Language column should get updated with Thai.
Can someone help?

[image]

Comment: Please provide the dataframe and the expected result :)

Comment: Value in column Expected result should replace the value in Language column

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```
df['Language'].fillna(df['Expected Result'], inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for this.....but unfortunately this is not what I am looking for...let me try to reframe my query **Expected result column I have added manually its not in dataframe**. Data in comments column is getting translated using translator now the language of original comment should get updated in language column. For eg if the original comment is in English value of that particular cell of language column should get updated with English or if the original language is Thai it should get updated with Thai.